# What does !@ mean in php?

Tags: php, error-handling

I have the following code in a very old php code base

```
$memcached_obj = new Memcached();
!@$memcached_obj->addServer($m,$memCachePort,true);
$memcached_obj->delete('feature_flags');
```

I know what each does separately but I can't figure out the purpose for both being used in conjunction and we don't have anyone who remembers that code anymore. My best educated guess is that someone wanted to suppress the error and also invert the return value for the addServer function call (which return true on success and false on failure), throw it in a variable and do something with it but the code has been deleted since then.

I would appreciate any help in figuring out if my guess is right or if !@ has some secret purpose.

Comment: the `@` is an [error reporting operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) the `!` is a [logical not operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) My best guess would fall in line with your assumption